# Images lose their position in Frame/Relative Layout after the user finished dragging

Tags: android, android-layout, draggable

I have implemented zoom and dragging functionality which works fine, meanwhile I am facing the problem that as soon as drag ends, images went back to right bottom corner. Below is the code I am using for dragging. Can you guide me of how to control/ remember my last dragged position.

```
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    frameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    frameLayout.buildDrawingCache();
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
    frameLayout.draw(c);
    frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);`

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    if (x < 0) {

        img_must_cities.setX(0);
        img_must_cities.setY(y);
        img_road_names.setX(0);
        img_road_names.setY(y);

        x = 0;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "x=0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (y < 0) {

        img_must_cities.setY(0);
        img_must_cities.setX(x);
        img_road_names.setY(0);
        img_road_names.setX(x);

        y = 0;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "y=0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (x > bm.getWidth()) {
        x = bm.getWidth() - 20;
        img_must_cities.setX(x);
        img_must_cities.setY(y);
        img_road_names.setX(x);
        img_road_names.setY(y);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "x=bitmap.maxwidth(}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (y > bm.getHeight()) {
        y = bm.getHeight() - 20;
        img_must_cities.setX(x);
        img_must_cities.setY(y);
        img_road_names.setX(x);
        img_road_names.setY(y);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "y=bitmap.maxheight(}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (x > 0 && x < bm.getWidth() && y > 0 && y < bm.getHeight()) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int pixel = bm.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);

        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.e("COORDINATES", "Touch coordinates : x" + String.valueOf(x) + "y" + String.valueOf(y));

                img_must_cities.setX(x);
                img_must_cities.setY(y);
                img_road_names.setX(x);
                img_road_names.setY(y);
                inRed = Color.red(pixel);
                inBlue = Color.blue(pixel);
                inGreen = Color.green(pixel);
                Log.e("Colors", "R:" + inRed + " G:" + inGreen + " B:" + inBlue);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                Log.e("COORDINATES", "Touch coordinates : x" + String.valueOf(x) + "y" + String.valueOf(y));
                img_must_cities.setX(x);
                img_must_cities.setY(y);
                img_road_names.setX(x);
                img_road_names.setY(y);
                inRed = Color.red(pixel);
                inBlue = Color.blue(pixel);
                inGreen = Color.green(pixel);
                Log.e("Colors", "R:" + inRed + " G:" + inGreen + " B:" + inBlue);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (x < 0 && x < bm.getWidth() && y < 0 && y < bm.getHeight()) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int pixel = bm.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);

        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.e("COORDINATES", "Touch coordinates : x" + String.valueOf(x) + "y" + String.valueOf(y));

                img_must_cities.setX(x);
                img_must_cities.setY(y);
                img_road_names.setX(x);
                img_road_names.setY(y);
                inRed = Color.red(pixel);
                inBlue = Color.blue(pixel);
                inGreen = Color.green(pixel);
                Log.e("Colors", "R:" + inRed + " G:" + inGreen + " B:" + inBlue);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                Log.e("COORDINATES", "Touch coordinates : x" + String.valueOf(x) + "y" + String.valueOf(y));

                img_must_cities.setX(x);
                img_must_cities.setY(y);
                img_road_names.setX(x);
                img_road_names.setY(y);
                inRed = Color.red(pixel);
                inBlue = Color.blue(pixel);
                inGreen = Color.green(pixel);
                Log.e("Colors", "R:" + inRed + " G:" + inGreen + " B:" + inBlue);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For "last position" you means when the user drop the image?

Comment: @Erik Minarini, yes when the user drops image, it should remain at that very place. But in my case, it somehow return to right bottom corner.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try that:

initially, save your x and y, when you detect the `ACTION_DROP` event use `getX()` and `getY()` if you want to log them, then set your x and y to the initial values.

Here you can find the documentation for the events: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html